# How to use php to print a specific value from json?

Tags: php, json

hi i need from this json:

```
{
   "data":{
      "user_quota":[
         {
            "group_limit":10240,
            "quota":0,
            "support_share_quota":false,
            "used":10.09765625,
            "volume":"\/volume1"
         }
      ]
   },
   "success":true
}


$decode = json_decode($curl, true);
```

Need print this line: "group_limit": xxxx

How do i write it?
Although I'm looking for how hedlam I can't find anything functional to list it

Thank you

Comment: You could `print_r($decode);` to see what the decoded array looks like and then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the data supplied, this is relatively simple:

```
$decode = json_decode($curl, true);
echo $decode["data"]["user_quota"][0]["group_limit"];
```

Outputs:

```
10240
```

You could also decode this as an *object*, which would be my preference (note the missing `true` parameter from `json_decode`:

```
$decode = json_decode($curl);
echo $decode->data->user_quota[0]->group_limit;
```

Outputs:

```
10240
```

However, what will happen if there is more than one `user_quota`?  Do you need to loop through these.  The question isn't clear.

Comment: i taking from curl .. i need maybe transfer to json in php..
when is use this: json_encode($curl) 
original output is: {"data":{"user_quota":[{"group_limit":10240,"quota":0,"support_share_quota":false,"used":10.09765625,"volume":"\/volume1"}]},"success":true}

Comment: @ondravirag Yes that's exactly what I've shown in the code above... Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: It does work if the data in `$curl` matches what you claim it does: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef2230d9a62fd70cf74ed06c04b05eab86a250ce

Comment: the variable $curl is formed from the url and the output it has as we described:
{"data":{"user_quota":[{"group_limit":10240,"quota":0,"support_share_quota":false,"used":10.09765625,"volume":"\/volume1"}]},"success":true}

it follows itself and not below it. Maybe some function to convert

Comment: @ondravirag Why would you need to convert it?  It's already a valid object\array when you run it through `json_decode`...  What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: original code is here:

    $home_group_limit = 0;
    $home_used = 0;
    foreach ($curl['data']['user_quota'] as $volume) {
       foreach ($volume['shares'] as $shares){
        if ($shares['name'] == 'homes'){
            $home_group_limit = $shares['group_limit'];
            $home_used = $shares['used'];
        }
       }
    }

but is not working .. output from curl url is:

{"data":{"user_quota":[{"group_limit":10240,"quota":0,"support_share_quota":false,"used":10.09765625,"volume":"\/volume1"}]},"success":true}


Where is problem please ? :)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0720251bece1fa1bc1f44907244aacc16585f52

Comment: @ondravirag http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46fb15f69ee7810353d97fb4fde78c9e7d84c002

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $curl is the serialised json response, this will print the value in that node.

```
echo $decode['data']['user_quota'][0]['group_limit'];
```